# How to join the three tables eav_attribute, catalog_eav_attribute, eav_attribute_label using attribute_id in magento 2

Tags: database, attributes, magento2.2.2

How to join the three tables **eav_attribute**, **catalog_eav_attribute**, **eav_attribute_label** using **attribute_id** in magento 2.

I am using the below query, But no get proper answer.
I have created the export script to export attribute and its options using below code.

```
 $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');

    $connection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
    $select_attribs = $connection->select()
            ->from(array('ea' => $resource->getTableName('eav_attribute')))
            ->join(array('c_ea' => $resource->getTableName('catalog_eav_attribute')), 'ea.attribute_id = c_ea.attribute_id');
    $select_prod_attribs = $select_attribs->where('(ea.entity_type_id = ' . $ent_type_id . ')AND (ea.is_user_defined = 1)')
            ->order('ea.attribute_id ASC');
    $product_attributes = $connection->fetchAll($select_prod_attribs);
    $select_attrib_option = $select_attribs
            ->join(array('e_ao' => $resource->getTableName('eav_attribute_option'), array('option_id')), 'c_ea.attribute_id = e_ao.attribute_id')
            ->join(array('e_aov' => $resource->getTableName('eav_attribute_option_value'), array('value')), 'e_ao.option_id = e_aov.option_id and store_id = 0')
            ->order('e_ao.attribute_id ASC');
    echo $select_attrib_option;
    exit;
    $product_attribute_options = $connection->fetchAll($select_attrib_option);
```

It gives final query like this and works great

SELECT `ea`.*, `c_ea`.*, `e_ao`.*, `e_aov`.* FROM `eav_attribute` AS `ea`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `c_ea` ON ea.attribute_id = c_ea.attribute_id
 INNER JOIN `eav_attribute_option` AS `e_ao` ON c_ea.attribute_id = e_ao.attribute_id
 INNER JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `e_aov` ON e_ao.option_id = e_aov.option_id and store_id = 0 WHERE ((ea.entity_type_id = 4)AND (ea.is_user_defined = 1)) ORDER BY `ea`.`attribute_id` ASC, `e_ao`.`attribute_id` ASC;

**But After that, I also need Main Attribute Description, So I wish to join another table eav_attribute_label using attribute id** So I have changed my code like below

```
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');

    $connection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
    $select_attribs = $connection->select()
    ->from(array('ea' => $resource->getTableName('eav_attribute')))
    ->join(array('ea_l' => $resource->getTableName('eav_attribute_label')), 'ea.attribute_id = ea_l.attribute_id')
             //Added another table
    ->join(array('c_ea' => $resource->getTableName('catalog_eav_attribute')), 'ea.attribute_id = c_ea.attribute_id');

    $select_prod_attribs = $select_attribs->where('(ea.entity_type_id = ' . $ent_type_id . ')AND (ea.is_user_defined = 1)')
            ->order('ea.attribute_id ASC');
    $product_attributes = $connection->fetchAll($select_prod_attribs);
    $select_attrib_option = $select_attribs
            ->join(array('e_ao' => $resource->getTableName('eav_attribute_option'), array('option_id')), 'c_ea.attribute_id = e_ao.attribute_id')
            ->join(array('e_aov' => $resource->getTableName('eav_attribute_option_value'), array('value')), 'e_ao.option_id = e_aov.option_id and store_id = 0')
            ->order('e_ao.attribute_id ASC');
    echo $select_attrib_option;
    exit;
    $product_attribute_options = $connection->fetchAll($select_attrib_option);
```

**But it throws error like below**

```
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'store_id' in on clause is ambiguous
```

Comment: Sri, check My answer it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

You need to specify the `tableName` since multiple tables contains the same column name (`store_id`).

Add your table name like `table.store_id`.

Comment: Can you please tell , How do I  add store id in my code

Comment: Can you explain where i need to change

Comment: you should replace this line `->join(array('e_aov' => $resource->getTableName('eav_attribute_option_value'), array('value')), 'e_ao.option_id = e_aov.option_id and e_aov.store_id = 0')`

Comment: Replace `store_id` to `e_aov.store_id`

Comment: Hi Nikunj the error is solved, but it displays the records only the attribute which has description, failed to get all the attributes and its options.

Comment: @Sri I give you solution for your error, if you have anthor issue you can create new post for the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78873/discussion-between-nikunj-vadariya-and-sri).